# Using ack/grep with globstar option for big directory tree (performance issue?)

Tags: performance, bash, grep, ack, file-search

I'd like to use `globstar` option '`**`' of bash to search files with a certain directories, as is customary is used with `grep`. However, the following command just started and did nothing

```
ack PATTERN ~/projects/**/trunk/
```

How I can search in files with `ack` using similar search place?

***EDIT:*** I tried to perform same line on model directory with few files. And it works fine. So, it looks like that operator `**` demands too much resources (it has a recursion, I guess) and when I execute the command, it just iterate through file tree. By the way, the following command slows down the computer and it was a reason I tried `ack` command.

```
grep -r PATTERN ~/projects/**/trunk/
```

So, I'd like to know is there some workaround to gain my goal (not necessarily with `**`)?

Comment: Does it work correctly on those files if you don't specify the path(s) (if you are in one of those directories for example)?

Comment: @Etan - `ack pattern_to_seek` works correctly, but I'd like to shrink output

Comment: It works from one of those trunk directories and finds the files you expect it to find (that is files *in* those trunk directories)? Also do you need `**` here? Do you really have `trunk` directories at arbitrary depths under `projects` that you want to search all at once?

Comment: @EtanReisner - `trunk` directories can have from 2 to 4 depth under `projects`

Comment: If `ack` works in one of those directories then it should work when given one of those directories manually I would think. You could also use `find` to get the list of directories to search through and/or use more specific manually listed out single-glob paths to the possible trunk locations.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Thank you. It looks like a prospective solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`\find -X . -type d -name trunk | xargs -L 1 ack PATTERN`

The `-X` argument, from the `find` manual

> -X      Permit find to be safely used in conjunction with xargs(1).  If a file name contains any of the delimiting characters used by xargs(1), a diagnostic message is displayed on standard error, and the
>                file is skipped.  The delimiting characters include single (`' '') and double (` " '') quotes, backslash (``\''), space, tab and newline characters.

EDIT: Based on the comments better solution may to be (works on BSD/GNU find/xargs AFAICT):

`\find . -type d -name trunk -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 ack PATTERN`

I guess it will depend on whether your end command can take the arguments with the funny filenames

Comment: What is that `-X` argument? Also this has potential problems with files with "odd" names.

Comment: @EtanReisner I edited the answer to explain it. The trick is that `xargs` has problems with _odd_ names, `-X` is meant to protect xargs from these.

Comment: Ah, BSD find. GNU find has other solutions for that problem... namely `find -print0` and `xargs -0` which don't drop files from processing.

Comment: @EtanReisner I modified the solution based on your comments. I must admit I normally do not mind dropping names using `-X` since whenever I run `find` with `xargs` it is within dir trees where everything is under strict control.

Comment: There is a very qualitative difference between dropping and processing "odd" input when doing the latter is safe. When processing is not safe dropping is **infinitely** better than processing unsafely however. So for a fix in only one of the tools `-X` is certainly reasonable. That being said you can do without `xargs -0` with a manual shell loop (and even without `-print0` with a manual `-printf` format, at least in GNU find` for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 1):

The shell expands `**` -- that is if you've first set `shopt -s globstar` ***and*** are using Bash 4.0 or higher. In that case, you can look to see exactly what files the shell is matching to your `globstar`. Try these:

```
$ ls -d ~/projects/**/trunk/
```

or:

```
$ echo ~/projects/**/trunk/
```

Then, go get a cup of coffee because `globstar` can take quite a long time to execute. You might find that you're not even hitting a file where `grep` or `ack` returns a match. That's minutes of your life you've wasted and you'll never get back. Might as well have watched the [Star Wars Holiday Special](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Holiday_Special). At least with that you could make some sort of drinking game.

The problem with `globstar` is that the shell is forced to walk down your entire directory tree trying to match `**`. Then, the shell doesn't report back its results until it has found each and every file. It's slow, and very inefficient.

Here's what happened on my system:

```
$ time ls -d ~/projects/**/trunk
/Users/david/projects/foo/trunk           /Users/david/projects/barfoo/trunk
/Users/david/projects/bar/trunk           /Users/david/projects/foofoo/trunk
/Users/david/projects/foobar/trunk        /Users/david/projects/trunk

real    0m18.19s
user    0m0.52s
sys     0m15.83s
```

I stood staring at the terminal for almost 20 seconds before those six results popped up. If I did `~/**/trunk`, it takes over 20 minutes without a single result being returned (I killed it after 20 minutes).

And here's the equivalent with `find`:

```
$ time find ~/projects -name trunk
/Users/david/projects/foo/trunk
/Users/david/projects/bar/trunk
/Users/david/projects/foobar/trunk
/Users/david/projects/barfoo/trunk
/Users/david/projects/foofoo/trunk
/Users/david/projects/trunk

real    0m4.09s
user    0m0.20s
sys     0m0.91s
```

The `find` was four times faster than using `globstar`. Plus, the results are returned as soon as they're found. You're better off using `find`:

```
$ find ~/projects -name trunk -type d -exec ack PATTERN {}\;
```